# Best way to implement in angularjs list detail view hierarchy without reloading when going back

Tags: angularjs

i've the following hierarchy structure : Group -> Family -> products -> Product details.
each node is retrieve through an $http service.

i would like the user to be able to drill down until the final product details and i would also like no reloads when the user hits the back button as parents never changes.

i've succeeded to build the first part using routes and it works pefectly but now each time i want to go back the controller of the parent view (last view) is reloaded and i don't know how to avoid this reloading.

i am thinking of changing my way of doing it by having only 1 view (while 4 before) and manage the drill down through a directive, do you think it could be considered as a good practice ? how would you implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), since one of its main feature is the ability to nest states & views.

Have a look at the [UI-Router Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample), source code [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/sample).